# Difference between Android traffic , Tablet traffic and Mobile traffic in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, traffic, android

I would like to know the difference among Tablet traffic, Android traffic and mobile traffic.

Whilst in my opinion Tablets and mobiles can have Android OS, and would like to know the difference among three.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to look in two separate locations within Google Analytics, as mobile device reports and operating system reports are in different places.

To get to the operating system reports, open Google Analytics and naviagate to `Audience > Technology > Browser & OS` in the left navigation menu.

[image]

Then, set the `Primary Dimension` as `Operating System`.

[image]

To get the tablet and mobile traffic, go back to the left-side navigation menu, and click `Audience > Mobile > Overview`.

[image]